Soft starter for inductive loads (motors)
I am a beginner level EE working for a small company. There is a three-phase (whose only two are controlled) soft-starter project (for 1/4CV motors) that has never worked as intended. The company tasked me with making it work.
What happens is that it starts the motor slow for a franction of a second, goes to full voltage and at the end of the ramp comes back to control the voltage. A mess. It works for resistive loads, I can see the firing angle of the triacs increasing slowly on the oscilloscope.
I read somewhere (might have been here) that one has to get feedback of the triacs state (current/ no current) instead of the line voltage (which is what we are using for tracking the firing angles) in order to start firing the triacs at the right moment.
Experienced engineers, how can I go about this challenge? what is the way of implementing a 3~ soft starter for small induction motors?
Edit: The objective is to start the motor in a soft way, slowly increasing torque. The triacs are always active, there is no bypass (after the gradual start the triacs act basically as a short).

What's the goal of the soft-starter? To reduce inrush current, or to reduce torque stress on the load? Or?  I'm not clear on what the triacs are doing, are they only active during the soft-start, or are they used to control the motor during operation? Is there some kind of ESC?  I think we need a lot more information on the circuit, the controller, and the load in order to help.

The objective is to start the motor in a soft way, slowly increasing torque. The triacs are always active, there is no bypass (after the gradual start the triacs act basically as a short). There is no ESC, we use a STM8 to get feedback from the mains sinusoidal voltage and fire the triacs.

You're right, the inductive load makes triac control challenging.  Some info here: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an308-triac-analog-control-circuits-for-inductive-loads-stmicroelectronics.pdf
